# docker container create a container ,but can not be ran

Tags: docker

First, I have a Dockerfile like this:

```
from centos6
CMD /bin/cat
```

I am sure that above image and above cmd in the file is available, and then I built a image using `docker build -t china .`
In general, when we start a container by `docker run -tid --name china china`,The container started go into running, because `/bin/cat` exits never.  Actually, it is ture.

And yet when I run following command, a container created will stop, because command `/bin/cat` exited:

```
docker rm -f china
docker container create --name china
docker start china
```

Finally, I got following results:

```
Error response from daemon: Container 23cb59ed034c093b73bd636f7453fc079f23d1acff1f1e5246464a29ea57b308 is not running
```

I launched a container by two ways, but I got different results.I do not know reasons why it cause this problem.

I can provide someone wants to help me to solve this problem with my computer by remote, such as windows's remote desktop.

Comment: show the result of 'docker ps'

Comment: What does your container actually do?  What's the application built into the container?

Comment: I redescribed this problem ,help me please.